# Capping alpha for sprite blending

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, opengl-3

In modern OpenGL, I am drawing a series of adjacent sprites using a textured quad for each sprite (as in a brush stroke). What technique could I use to draw the sprites without the alpha value accumulating?

To be clear, let me show an example.

Assume my sprite is a semi-transparent circle, as such:
[image]

If I draw two adjacent sprites, I would get this:
[image]

Which is very normal, though what I want to get is this:
[image]

Where the alpha value of the result is the maximum of the alphas of the source and dest, as if they are part of the same visual layer.

I assume this involves my [blend function](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml).
Currently it is:

```
 glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Which blend function or other technique could I use to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

(Ab)use the stencil buffer:

1. Clear stencil buffer to 0xff
2. Foreach circle, only write (& blend) into the color & stencil buffers where the stencil buffer is 0xff.  If the stencil & depth tests succeed set the stencil value for the fragment to zero.

This way you can only write (& blend) a color pixel *once* until you clear the stencil buffer again.

Example:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void quad()
{
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glVertex2i( -1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1,  1 );
    glVertex2i( -1,  1 );
    glEnd();
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    // clear stencil buffer to all 1s
    glClearStencil( 0xff );
    glClear( GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT );

    // turn on stencil testing & make sure we don't mask out any bits
    glEnable( GL_STENCIL_TEST );
    glStencilMask( 0xff );

    // only allow fragments through to the color/depth buffers if
    // the stencil buffer at that point is 0xff
    glStencilFunc( GL_EQUAL, 0xff, 0xff );

    // if the stencil/depth tests succeed for a fragment, 
    // zero out the stencil buffer at that point;
    // that way you can only write to a color buffer pixel once
    glStencilOp( GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_ZERO );

    glEnable( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef( -0.5, -0.5, 0 );
    glColor4ub( 255, 0, 0, 128 );
    quad();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef( 0.5, 0.5, 0 );
    glColor4ub( 255, 0, 0, 128 );
    quad();
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_STENCIL );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write the detailed example, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Rotem: Comment out the `glEnable( GL_STENCIL_TEST )` line to see what the overlap blend looks like without the stencil buffer.

Comment: Note that in Modern GL you effectively need to test the alpha and `discard` the fragments which are fully transparent, otherwise you'll still perform the stencil test.

Comment: Finally had time to try this. I see now what @peppe means, though now sure how to go about implementing that.

Comment: Supposing you're sampling from a texture, in your fragment shader you'll have something like `vec4 sampledColor = texture(yourSampler, texCoord);`. You'll need to add `if (sampledColor.a == 0.0) discard;`.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem of outputting  the maximum, but rather outputs only the first transparent object. Sorting the objects, so  that the most opaque objects are rendered first solves this unless one object can have multiple alpha values.

Comment: @peppe Thanks, I was unfamiliar with the `discard` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing. It's hard to call it the answer, as I have changed the parameters of the question a bit, but I thought I would mention it for posterity.

Instead of using transparent sprites, I use fully opaque sprites.

I then render these to a texture, and then draw that texture with the desired opacity.